# Error upgrading from 2.9.2 to 3.0.1

Tags: customization, upgrade

I have my wordpress install under svn.  I was on version 2.9.2. These were the steps I took:

- saved a copy of my current wordpress directory
- cd into my top level wordpress directory
- `svn up` (just to make sure that I have the latest of 2.9)
- `svn sw http://core.svn.wordpress.org/tags/3.0.1/ .` (upgrade)
- run wp-admin/upgrade.php
- got this error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_multisite() in *(my install directory)*/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 505"

I looked around and some people think it's a memory issue with PHP. So I tried the Memory Bump plugin and that didn't work.

Any ideas?

**Update:**
Found [this post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/call-to-undefined-function-is_multisite-after-wordpress-30-upgrade).  Downloaded the latest 3.0 tar and overwrote my wp-settings.php with the one in the download.

Get different errors now. "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare wp_load_image() (previously declared in /*myinstalldir*/wordpress/wp-includes/media.php:241) in /*myinstalldir*/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/image.php on line 168"

When I perform and `svn status` I see lots of 'S' flags (switched).  Do I have to be concerned with that?  wp-settings.php has that flag.

**Update:**
[Here's the output](http://pastebin.com/6bqPPpw6) of the above `svn sw` from the root Wordpress directory.

**Update:**
Output of `svn st` [here](http://pastebin.com/TJRhf0WZ). (Migrated the long listings to pastebin)

**Update:**
Output of `svn info`

```
Path: .
URL: http://core.svn.wordpress.org/tags/3.0.1
Repository Root: http://core.svn.wordpress.org
Repository UUID: 1a063a9b-81f0-0310-95a4-ce76da25c4cd
Revision: 15559
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: ryan
Last Changed Rev: 13165
Last Changed Date: 2010-02-15 09:38:59 -0800 (Mon, 15 Feb 2010)
```

Comment: Instead of updating your SVN working copy, have you tried the upgrade link from othe wp-admin section directly when logged in? It has worked without any problem for me on two WP installations already

Comment: I don't see any of the "S" flags you mentioned. Given a clean `svn sw` between revisions, `svn st` should be almost empty except for any themes and plugins you've added. Your paste looks like a checkout that has had an upgrade to WordPress 3 applied manually, outside the scope of Subversion. What's the output of `svn info` on the WordPress directory? Betting it says tag 2.9.2.

Comment: Also "U" is not a flag shown during status, it's an update flag. And status wouldn't attempt to delete a directory. So that doesn't seem to be the output of `svn st`.

Comment: Just updated with all the info that Adam was asking about.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @Marek : I actually just decided to try using the upgrade link from the admin section and it worked without a hitch! Even though now my code base is probably very different (in SVN's eyes) from the repo, I think I'm happy for now. If I have more time to spend, I may try to do a clean install from SVN for v3.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also used SVN before to update my wordpress installation. Up the working copied will get messed up very quickly with all the manual updates or files created by plugins.

I would always recommend to use the update functionality of wordpress if you only want to step from one tagged version to another one.

Although, I also use SVN for a local copy of wordpress to be able to quickly test my plugins in some old version real quick. I use Eclipse to switch from one to another tag and until now it worked out. But you'll never know.

**UPDATE**:
I just tried to switch a clean checkout of 2.9.2 to 3.0.1 which looks like it is working, but I can only see the backend and not the frontend of the default single blog.

**UPDATE**:
What even the debug mode doesn't tell me: As the default pre WP 3.0 theme is no longer available I just have to switch to the new "2010" theme. Now everything is working.

So switching does work, but as I said before, your working copy usually get's messed up with a lot of files that might cause some problems updating your WP copy with SVN switch.

Comment: I used the 'upgrade' link in the wp-admin section and it worked. The error is still a mystery to me, but I'll leave that to another time...or I'll just let it be.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you ran `svn sw` in a subdirectory, rather than the top-level WordPress directory. We may be able to help you recover, if you can't just checkout a clean copy and move over your plugins and themes. The full output of `svn st` would be helpful, as well as `svn info` for any directory that may have been switched independent of its parent.